# Wordpress Query on a Page using Allow PHP in Posts and Pages Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

It does what I want it to do, displays a certain category of posts in a column on a page. Right now its just the title, but I want to link that title and the permalink section isnt working, or rather the href.

```
[php]
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=3' );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul style="list-style:none;">';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . '<a href="the_permalink();">' . get_the_title() . '[/a]'. '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
[/php]
```

It links to subdomain.domain.com/site/the_permalink(); instead pulling the permalink for that post and linking to it.

Answer (score 0):

the_permalink(); return to echo your link.
You need to return only string. For this you can use `get_the_permalink($post->ID);`
Because your permalink function is inside of echo function.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter the a-tag you start with HTML, if you close it you change to BBCode.

Answer (score 0):

Fatih is right, you need to use [`get_permalink`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) function. Since you're inside the loop, you don't need to specify the parameter (`$post->ID`).

Also, you need to switch back to PHP (that is your main problem) as you did with `get_the_title` function. There are multiple syntax issues with your code (brackets!).

The line should go like this:

```
echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
```

Learn the difference between `echo` and `return` in (not only) PHP functions!